# difference in printing zero in cout and printf

Tags: c++, printf, cout, zero, epsilon

with

```
printf("%lf\n",-1.0+0.9+0.1);
```

result is

```
0.000000
```

while with

```
cout<<-1.0+0.9+0.1;
```

result is

```
 2.77556e-17
```

again, if i change

```
 cout<<0.9+0.1+-1.0;
```

result is

```
 0
```

why this different behavior simply inverting the sum?and why 2.77556e-17?is it the machine epsilon?and why I get it and not zero?

Comment: Try printing with `%e` rather than `%f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::cout` by default for floating point variables is similar to the `%g` flag rather than the `%lf` flag in `printf`. In order to get the same behaviour, you have to pass [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) to the stream, e.g.:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << 0.9+0.1+-1.0;
```